# Can't import os in python

Tags: python, import, operating-system, mkdir, pyzo

I get this message when trying to import os while using Pyzo 4.10.2 :

> ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Here is the code I tried :

```
from os import *
os.mkdir('Repertoire_test')
```

I also tried `import os` previously.

When I try it in python directly (the black background interpreter) it works though, as i can see the folder in my hard drive :

```
Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.mkdir('Rpertoire_test')
>>>
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be changing

```
from os import *
```

to

```
import os
```

If this doesn't work I would try reinstalling python

Answer (score 0):

if the error is coming from your conda, it's certainly because the environment is not activated, try:

```
conda update conda
activate base
```

restart your working station then:

```
conda activate (environment name)
```

if the error persists try the previous steps preceded by:

```
sudo -s
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this your actual code? Cause this should cause another error as you are importing everything from os with * but trying to access with os.foo(). This should cause an NameError (I guess). Try:

```
import os   
os.mkdir('Repertoire_test')
```

After correcting this try another editor/IDE. The error indicates that somewhere in your code there is an invalid character wich is not displayed and your IDE does not get this. Or copy the code into a gedit/notepad etc. and try again